# Optotriac+triac: how do I calculate the gate resistor

Tags: opto-isolator, thyristor

I am building a small circuit to turn on/off a 200W heater. I am using a `MOC3023` and a `BT136`. At the datasheet of the the optotriac, this circuit  is recommended:
[image]

My question is how is the 180Ohm resistor value determined. I understand that it conducts for a very short time, but not much more. Is this a valid value for both 230VAC and 12VAC? Is 1/4W resistor always suitable?

Comment: Did you mean 120VAC?

Comment: @PhilFrost - good question, it's quite possible he did given the 200W heater mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 180Ω resistor will probably need to be altered for 12VAC, what value it needs to be depends on the minimum trigger/latching current needed for the main triac. Also, a 0.25W resistor is only suitable if the wattage doesn't exceed 0.25W, so you need to calculate max voltage across it times current through it.

This [Fairchild app note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-3003.pdf.pdf) is worth a read for deciding on the values of components to use.

For a resistive load the circuit shown below:

[image: Triac Circuit]

The relevant part of this note with the formulas is:

**Triac Driving Requirements**

Figure 2 shows a simple triac driving circuit using the 
MOC3011M. The maximum surge current rating of the MOC3011M sets the minimum value of R1 through the equation:

R1 (min) = Vin(pk)/1.2A

If we are operating on the 115 Vac nominal line voltage, Vin (pk) = 180 V, then:
R1(min) = Vin(pk)/1.2A = 150 ohms.
In practice, this would be a 150 or 180 ohm resistor.

If the triac has IGT = 100 mA and VGT = 2 V, then the voltage Vin necessary to trigger the triac will be given by:
VinT = R1 * IGT + VGT + VTM = 20 V.

Comment: I found my answer at the bottom left corner of page 2 of the cited by you document. IMO the answer will be improved, should that information be edited into it, with simple explanations.

Comment: @Vorac - Good stuff, will edit the info into the answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, and unclear about original question. Is R1 wattage in this case `VinT*IGT=20V*100mA=2W` or `R1*IGT*IGT=150E*100mA*100mA=1.5W` or maybe something completely else, since 2W seems quite a lot.

Comment: The first formula gives you a lower bound: R1_min = Vin(pk) / I_FSM. The second formula an upper bound: R1_max = (Vin - V_GT - V_TM) / I_GT. Finally you can put various commercial resistor Watt ratings into R1 = Vin² / W and see which ones give you a R1 within the other bounds.